# Scheme to Python: most elegant translation of a recursive procedure?

Tags: python, recursion, scheme

I recent read again the beautiful intro to recursion in the 'simply scheme' book (here's the [link](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~bh/ssch11/recursion.html) to the relevant chapter), where this recursive procedure is introduced (in the **scheme** language):

```
(define (downup wd)
  (if (= (count wd) 1)
      (se wd)
      (se wd (downup (bl wd)) wd)))

> (downup 'toe)
(TOE TO T TO TOE)

> (downup 'banana)
(BANANA BANAN BANA BAN BA B BA BAN BANA BANAN BANANA)
```

I tried to translate that procedure into **python**, which I use in my day job. Here's the result:

```
def recursivefun(word):
    if len(word) == 1: 
        return word
    else:
        x = []
        x.append(word)
        x.extend(recursivefun(word[1:]))
        x.append(word)
        return x

print recursivefun("ciao")
# ==> ['ciao', 'iao', 'ao', 'o', 'ao', 'iao', 'ciao']
```

So my question is: is there a better way to represent this recursive procedure in python? Or maybe a more 'elegant' way?

Comment: I just noticed that `downup` in your example chops of letters at the end, whereas `recursivefun` chops off letters from the front.  Is that difference intentional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to closely represent the original recursive Scheme function:

```
def downup(word):
    if len(word) <= 1:
        return [word]
    return [word] + downup(s[1:]) + [word]
```

Note that your own function returns a string if the length of the passed in string is 1 and a list otherwise.  This could lead to surprising behaviour.  Try

```
def recursivefun(word):
    if len(word) == 2:
        return word
    else:
        x = []
        x.append(word)
        x.extend(recursivefun(word[1:]))
        x.append(word)
        return x

print recursivefun("banana")
```

for example, which prints

```
['banana', 'anana', 'nana', 'ana', 'n', 'a', 'ana', 'nana', 'anana', 'banana']
```

which might be different from what you expected.

Comment: +1 for helping me understand the Scheme version (and also just a overall elegant solution)

Comment: thanks a lot what you pointed out is really useful! btw in your 'translation' above you used both 's' and 'word' to represent the same variable .. you might wanna change that!

Answer (score 2):

Refactored:

```
def recursivefun(word):
  if len(word) == 1: 
    return [word]
  else:
    return [word] + recursivefun(word[1:]) + [word]
```

Keep in mind we had to return [word] in the first branch because when you concatenate recursivefun() on line 5, it expects a list.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* possible to work with strings instead of lists:

```
def downup(wd):
    if len(wd) == 1:
        return wd

    return ' '.join([wd, downup(wd[:-1]), wd])

print downup("TOE")
print downup("BANANA")
```

prints

```
TOE TO T TO TOE
BANANA BANAN BANA BAN BA B BA BAN BANA BANAN BANANA
```

Answer (score 0):

And just for comparision it in list comprehension:

```
w ='BANANA'
print('('+' '.join(w[:n] for n in list(range(len(w)+1,1,-1)) + list(range(1,len(w)+1)))+')')
```

==>

(BANANA BANAN BANA BAN BA B BA BAN BANA BANAN BANANA)